# What formats does Chatter accept in a feedItem or comment? Specifically, can a user insert html, bbcode or markdown in a feed post or comment?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

If a user has a need to post inline markup, bbcode or markdown, what can Chatter support outside of normal text in a feedItem or comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatter only supports plain text without markup. According to this Idea, it is not a planned feature. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Hjs6AAC

Comment: Actually there is some basic rich text support planned for the Winter '16 release (but for feed items only, not comments) -- safe harbor. I work at Salesforce and will see if I can get the IdeaExchange info updated.

Comment: @alouie That Idea looks like it was reopened and then possibly marked as delivered a second time. Any chance you know its current status?